# create a formatted data file filled with random values

Tags: windows, data

I need to find a tool that i can use to create a large file of up to 5000 lines (or more).

Each line must be formatted like such

> **[30 Random Characters], [0-150] [Single Char (S,M,L)] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]**

please note the spaces in between each field.

if the first 30 random characters could be changed into names that would be a lot better but isn't really important.

Here is an example of some lines.

**Eddy Mercx, 72 M 1:10 1:59 2:58**

**Jocelyn Lovell, 60 M 1:10 0:00 1:34 W**

**Jason Gaudet, 28 M 1:10 2:11 3:09**

**Claude Van Gogh, 20 M 1:10 2:25 3:24**

I've been looking online for a bit and cant find any tools that can create formatted data files like this, i need such file for testing out a program and want to make sure i have a lot of test data to work with.

I'm working with windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you're looking for a reverse Regex generator, like [Text from Regex](https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-from-regex)

```
[A-Za-z]{30}, ([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0-4][0-9]|150) [SML] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
```

where

- `[A-Za-z]{30}` generates a 30 character long text with only alpha characters
- `,` creates a comma
- `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0-4][0-9]|150)` creates numbers from 0-9 or 10...99 or 100..149 or 150
- `[SML]` chooses one of these
- `[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]` is already valid Regex

Here's an example of what it creates:

```
HKibmNZfQqCfQsUEYSdhotpdKsBveO, 150 L 59:55 22:67 02:01
```

There are similar websites, but not many which can create a certain amount of output.

That said, all your examples do not match your specification, especially the numbers `x:xx` must have a leading 0 according the specification. In the second example, the `W` at the end is not allowed